# aws private subnet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, networking, amazon-vpc

On my AWS account, I have an RDS in a private subnet. A third party tool needs to access this RDS. I have whitelisted the third party's specific IP addresses but have not taken care of internet access yet. What would I need in front of the RDS/Private subnet in order for the third party's tool to access the RDS instance? Would a NAT Gateway take care of my need or does that only handle egress traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need a NAT gateway, a public IP address associated with the gateway and routes to the RDS.

More details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)